# Doing four string manipulations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to manipulate a string with these rules:

1. Replace multiple spaces with one space
2. Remove space in front of a dot
3. Space between two single (!) characters and dot should be removed: `i. e.` -> `i.e.`
4. Remove leading and trailing spaces

So this is what I come up with:

```
string = string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
string = string.replace(/\s\./, '.');
// ??
string = string.replace(/\.+$/, '');
```

I don't know how to take care of rule 3 and maybe everything can be merged together.

Comment: I'll answer these quickly... But rule 1 can be simplified to \s[2,] to replace 2 or more  I'll start on 3 now.

Comment: Is it specifically only "i. e." that should be transformed to "i.e.", or should something like "a. u." be transformed to "a.u."?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You are right: a. u. should get a.u.; x. y. should get x.y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine this into:

```
string = string.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').replace(/\s+\./g, '.').
                replace(/([!.])\s+([a-z])\b/ig, '$1$2').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

- Instead of `\s\s+` better to use `\s{2,}`
- `([!.])\s+([a-z]\b` will remove space after DOT or `!`, if followed by single letter.
- `^\s+|\s+$` will remove leading or trailing spaces

Comment: I need to remove space in front of dot, not after dot (your second comment)

Comment: In your example `i. e. -> i.e.` it is actually removing space **after** the `DOT`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was talking of the second rule: `Lorem ipsum .` should get `Lorem ipsum.` The third rule must be like described: Only remove spaces between single character dot and single character dot: `i. e. -> i.e.`. There should not be an effect to `i. em. -> i. em.`

Comment: What does `\b` mean?

Comment: `\b` is used for *word boundary*. That is to ensure we have a single letter after DOT & space.

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /(\w\.)\s(\w\.\s)/g;
const str = 'i. e. ';
const subst = '\$1\$2';

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

**Examples**

```
Input: "i. e. "
Output: "i.e "
Input: "a. g."
Output "a.g. "
```

The logic behind this is simple.  \w matches an [a-zA-Z0-9] character, . matches a . literally\s matches a space (as I'm sure you know)  The sequence was so rigid (1 character, 1 dot, 1 space, followed by 1 character and 1 dot) made it easier to just make and adjust the capture groups.